# Accessing a Directory and Creating and Writing to a File in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to write a program that

1. prompts the user to input a valid directory path
2. tells the user the directory is valid or invalid,
3. creates a file
4. writes a name, address and phone number to that file and
5. displays to the user the name, address and phone number written to the file.

I looked here and other sources and learned how to utilize tKinter, where a pop-up window allows the user to select the directory and file before writing to that file...but I need the program to prompt the user for the directory path and have it validated: That's where I'm stuck...

Thanks! Here is my code thus far:

```
print('Please choose a .txt file from the pop-up window')

from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename

Tk().withdraw()
filename = askopenfilename()
print(filename)

print('Now, please enter the .txt file name exactly as shown at the end of the directory path above: ')
file_name = input()

print('Now, please input your name: ')
name = input()
print('Next, enter your address: ')
address = input()
print('Finally, please enter your phone number: ')
phone = input()


file = open(file_name, 'w')
file.write(name + ", ")
file.write(address + ", ")
file.write(phone)
file.close()

file = open(file_name, 'r')
file_contents = file.read()
print('You input the following information into your chosen .txt file: ', file_contents)
print('Good-bye')
```

Comment: Can't you use askdirectory to prompt the user to select a directory?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `askdirectory()` as norie suggested:

```py
directory = askdirectory()

file_name = input('File name: ')
name = input('Your name: ')
address = input('Your address: ')
phone = input('Your phone: ')

file_content = ', '.join((name, address, phone))

with open(f'{directory}/{file_name}', 'w') as f:
    f.write(file_content)

print('File content:', file_content, sep='\n')
```

For windows use backslash to separate directory and file name or use [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html?highlight=path#module-pathlib) to be OS independent.